# Test for array containing a single empty string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, comparison

I am returning an array from a function in JavaScript and I need to be able to know when it contains nothing but a single empty string. When I print that value to the console, it returns this:

```
[""]
```

I get an error if I do the following:

```
if(myVar == [""]){
    // do something
}
```

How can I test for that value in that variable? jQuery answers are perfectly acceptable as well as plain JavaScript.

Comment: You should not get an error when doing `myVar == [""]`. What's the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use:

```
if( myVar instanceof Array && myVar.length === 1 && myVar[0] === '' ) {
// ....
}
```

Comment: `typeof myVar` will return "object", so this won't work. Use `myVar  instanceof Array` instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (myVar.length == 1 && myVar[0] == ""){   
}
```

Comment: What if `myVar` is `['',1,2,3]`

Comment: Edited, now it works if the array only contains strings.

Comment: You should change `==` to `===`.